# Implement a simple Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

### Purpose

I've never implemented a `DoublyLinkedList` and thought it would be a good data structure exercise. I tried using outside
resources as little as possible. I also tried to keep things as simple as possible

### Discussion

The `DoublyLinkedList` is made up of a `Node` `head`, a `Node` `tail`, and an `int` `length`. I did not genericize the
API to keep things simple - the API only deals with `int` values.

The API is

- `getHead` - gets the `Node` at the `head` of the linked list in `O(1)`
- `getTail` - gets the `Node` at the `tail` of the linked list in `O(1)`
- `getLength` - gets the `length` of the linked list in `O(1)`
- `isEmpty` - convenience method; returns `true` if `length` is `0` and `false` otherwise in `O(1)`
- `insertAtHead` - adds the input value at the `head` of the linked list in `O(1)`
- `insertAtTail` - adds the input value at the `tail` of the linked list in `O(1)`
- `insertAt` - adds the input value at some index in the linked list in `O(n)`
- `removeFirstOccurrence` - removes the first occurrence of the input value (if it exists in list) in `O(n)`
- `removeAt` - removes the node at the specified index in the linked list in `O(n)`
- `removeHead` - removes the node at the `head` of the linked list in `O(1)`
- `removeTail` - removes the node at the `tail` of the linked list in `O(1)`

Things I can improve:

- When inserting at / removing at a particular index, I could speed up execution time by picking to start
  at the beginning or end of the list based on which the index is closest to
- I tried adding a bunch of test cases, but I could have easily missed a case
- Is my API sane / reasonable / did I miss implementing any obvious methods?

### Implementation

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {
    public static class Node {
        private Node previous;
        private Node next;
        private int value;

        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Node getPrevious() {
            return previous;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int length;

    public DoublyLinkedList() {
    }

    public Node getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public Node getTail() {
        return tail;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return length == 0;
    }

    public void insertAtHead(int value) {
        insertNode(null, new Node(value), head);
    }

    public void insertAtTail(int value) {
        insertNode(tail, new Node(value), null);
    }

    public void insertAt(int value, int index) {
        if (index > length || index < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index of " + index + " is out of bounds");
        }

        Node node = new Node(value);
        Node previousNode = null;
        Node currentNodeAtIndex = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            previousNode = currentNodeAtIndex;
            currentNodeAtIndex = currentNodeAtIndex.next;
        }
        insertNode(previousNode, node, currentNodeAtIndex);
    }

    public void removeFirstOccurrence(int value) {
        Node currentNode = head;
        while (currentNode != null) {
            if (currentNode.value == value) {
                removeNode(currentNode);
                return;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
    }

    public void removeAt(int index) {
        if (index >= length || index < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index of " + index + " is out of bounds");
        }

        Node currentNodeAtIndex = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            currentNodeAtIndex = currentNodeAtIndex.next;
        }

        removeNode(currentNodeAtIndex);
    }

    public void removeHead() {
        removeNode(head);
    }

    public void removeTail() {
        removeNode(tail);
    }

    private void removeNode(Node node) {
        if (node.previous == null) {
            head = node.next;
        }

        if (node.next == null) {
            tail = node.previous;
        }

        if (node.previous != null) {
            node.previous.next = node.next;
        }

        if (node.next != null) {
            node.next.previous = node.previous;
        }

        length--;
    }

    private void insertNode(Node nodeBefore, Node node, Node nodeAfter) {
        node.next = nodeAfter;
        node.previous = nodeBefore;

        if (nodeBefore == null) {
            head = node;
        }

        if (nodeAfter == null) {
            tail = node;
        }

        if (nodeBefore != null) {
            nodeBefore.next = node;
        }

        if (nodeAfter != null) {
            nodeAfter.previous = node;
        }

        length++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is reasonable enough. A few details:

- All the methods of `Node` including constructor should be private. Your class should encapsulate and hide from the world the details of implementation. Besides, allowing the user to create instances of `Node` makes no sense because the user can't do anything with them.
- Methods `getHead` and `getTail` should return the value of the node rather than the Node itself. From the user's perspective your class deals with numbers, and the user expects the first and the last elements to be numbers as well.
- I would use a method, that accepts two parameters, to insert the node, not the method with 3 parameters as in your code. It would look like `private void insertAfter(Node node, Node newNode)`. You can easily get `nodeAfter` from the first parameter. If the first parameter is null, the method would add the `newNode` to the very beginning of the list.
- I'd follow the convention of `Deque` interface when naming methods. `getFirst(), getLast(), addFirst(value), addLast(value), removeFirst(), removeLast()`. Methods `pushFirst(value), pushLast(value), popFirst(), popLast()` would be also useful.
- Document your public api. Javadocs would be fine.

Comment: It might be worth recommending implementing the `Deque` interface to ensure that the contract is followed. There are a few more methods, but they should each only be a few lines of code.